# error (INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK)

Tags: java, android, apk

I keep recieving this error message. can you help me with this?

> 07/20 15:28:03: Launching app $ adb push C:\Users\La la
>   Meesh\Desktop\ELM\Veery\myVeery\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>   /data/local/tmp/myveery $ adb shell pm install -r
>   "/data/local/tmp/myveery"     pkg: /data/local/tmp/myveery Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
>
> $ adb shell pm uninstall myveery Unknown failure (Failure) Error while
>   Installing APK

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="myveery"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".myVs"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".NewVeery"
        android:parentActivityName=".myVs">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".myVs" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"></activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>

</application>
```

and here is

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myveery"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the **MinSdkVersion** of your app set satisfied by your running device. Also u can check for native library support. You can use an app and everything but they won’t give you all the CPU architecture information. For Android devices using a simple adb command would give you all the information about your device. For instance, issue the following command via cmd or terminal to find if device is arm, arm 64 or x86:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
```

Comment: can you explain more please